# Trying to refactor angularjs code to typescript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript, refactoring

I'm trying to refactor some AngularJS code to a new Angular 10 project. I need some help with doing that.

Here is the AngularJS code:

```
  replicateDesignDocsToDb = function (targetDb) {
    return $q(function (resolve, reject) {
        $log.info('@dbService | replicateDesignDocsToDb | start replication design docs to database ' + targetDb.name);
        targetDb.replicate.from(getRemoteDb(), {
            doc_ids: ['_design/app', '_design/query-index']
        }).on('complete', function (result) {
            $log.info('@dbService | replicateDesignDocsToDb | Design doc replicated from Remote Db');
            resolve(result);
        }).on('error', function (error) {
            $log.error('@dbService | replicateDesignDocsToDb | Error while replicating design doc from Remote Db: ', error);
            reject(error);
        });
    });
  };
```

And this is what I've tried myself:

```
  async replicateDesignDocsToDb() {
    const targetDb = this.getRemoteDb();
    return function (resolve, reject) {
      console.log(
        '@dbService | replicateDesignDocsToDb | start replication design docs to database ' +
          targetDb.Name
      );
      targetDb.replicate
        .from(this.getRemoteDb(), {
          doc_ids: ['_design/app', '_design/query-index'],
        })
        .on('complete', function (result) {
          console.log(
            '@dbService | replicateDesignDocsToDb | Design doc replicated from Remote Db'
          );
          resolve(result);
        })
        .on('error', function (error) {
          console.log(
            '@dbService | replicateDesignDocsToDb | Error while replicating design doc from Remote Db: ',
            error
          );
          reject(error);
        });
    };
  }
```

Comment: is there any error, is it working ?

Comment: @Tejeshree currently what I have doesn't work